# Can the header/nav be forced to fully fill the width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

So this is my problem with Bootstrap 3. So far, I've loved it. With CSS customization it feels like it can do ALMOST anything. However, I've hit a bit of a snag. I have a Header/Nav setup with the header displaying a centered image above the menu. Except, when the site is shrunk to fit... the header-menu refuses to fill out the entire length. It stops at the window edge.

Great, if you're looking at it full screen. If not, it forces a strange gap above the content to the edge of the page. How can I get it to fill to the "page" instead of the "window" gap?

```
    <body class="container-bg">

<header class="navheader">
    <span class="logo"><a href="/"><?PHP echo $this->Html->image('Logo.png', array('alt' => 'Teonnyn', 'style' => 'width: 256px, height: 64px')); ?></a></span>
</header>     

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-full">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left col-md-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/Posts"><b>Posts</b></a></li>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>                     

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>



<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="container-full" role="main">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><?php echo $this->Flash->render() ?></div>

            <div class="col-xs-10 well">
                <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
            </div>  

            <div class="col-xs-2  pull-right">
                <?
                if (!AuthComponent::user('id'))
                {
                ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                            <!--
                            <div class="social-buttons">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                            </div>
                            -->
                             <form id="login-dp" class="form well" role="form" method="post" action="/login" id="UserLoginForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                         <input class="form-control" name="data[User][username]" id="UserUsername" placeholder="Username" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="data[User][password]" class="form-control" id="UserPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                                        <div class="help-block"><a href="/Register">Register an account!</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox"> remember me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>                                      
                             </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>              

                <?PHP
                }
                ?>

                <?PHP
                if (AuthComponent::user('id'))
                {                   
                ?>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked well">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Dashboard</a></li>

                    <li role="presentation"><span><b>You</b></span></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/MultiPosts/Post"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Post</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Skills"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>Skills</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/SavedSocials"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>Social</a></li>

                    <li role="presentation"><span><b>Gallery</b></span></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>Images</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Gallery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Galleries</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Youtube"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span>Youtube</a></li>       

                    <li role="presentation"><span><b>Users</b></span></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Users</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Activations"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Activations</a></li>

                    <li role="presentation"><span><b>Structure</b></span></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Grid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>Grids</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Category"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>Categories</a></li>

                </ul>
                <?PHP
                }
                ?>                                          
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For life of me I cannot get the CSS to format properly for Stack, so here's a link: http://pastebin.com/xRqAaeXA

Comment: Sorry, but this is incomplete without an actually demo of your code.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you post your code.

Comment: As stated we can only guess without seeing the code. But, using developer tools you should be able to find the wrapper that is constraining the width and override the css with {Width: 100% !important}

Comment: Inspect your code and look if you've applied the `container` class on your header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin on your logo is one issue and the way you've implemented the grid system doesn't really make sense. Your form is being pushed off the page because it's being squeezed into a col-xs-2 and the class `container-full` isn't a replacement for `container-fluid`, rows/columns interact with the container classes so replacing/altering them can have adverse results.

See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Here are two examples to look into the stop the isse: See Snippet.

```css
html {
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container-bg {
  background-color: #e6eef2;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+31,4f4f4f+91 */
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Old browsers */
}
.logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-inverse {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 0.1em solid #ccc;
  /* wrap the calendar inside a box */
  width: 100%;
  /* define a width for the box */
  border: #000 dashed 1px;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.2em 0.8em #ccc;
  /* box shadow for better view */
}
.fc-widget-content,
.fc-day-header,
.fc-widget-header {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.fc-day-number {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
/* centered columns styles */

.message {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #286090;
  border: #000 solid 2px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: table;
}
.row-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
.col-centered {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /* reset the text-align */
  text-align: left;
  /* inline-block space fix */
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.fill {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-horizontal .control-label {
  text-align: left;
}
#login-dp {
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 14px 14px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
#login-dp .help-block {
  font-size: 12px
}
#login-dp .bottom {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  clear: both;
  padding: 14px;
}
#login-dp .social-buttons {
  margin: 12px 0
}
#login-dp .social-buttons a {
  width: 49%;
}
#login-dp .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn-fb {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}
.btn-fb:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #496ebc
}
.btn-tw {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #55acee;
}
.btn-tw:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #59b5fa;
}
@media(max-width:768px) {
  #login-dp {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #login-dp .bottom {
    background-color: inherit;
    border-top: 0 none;
  }
}
.blurb {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: #e7e7e7;
}
.datatable {
  font-size: 8px;
}
th {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="container-bg">
  <header class="navheader"> <span class="logo"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/256x64"></a></span>

  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-full">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left col-md-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/Posts"><b>Posts</b></a>

          </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>

              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" role="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 well">Something</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <form id="login-dp" class="form well" role="form" method="post" action="/login" id="UserLoginForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="data[User][username]" id="UserUsername" placeholder="Username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="data[User][password]" class="form-control" id="UserPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="help-block"><a href="/Register">Register an account!</a>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">remember me</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked well">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Dashboard</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>You</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/MultiPosts/Post"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Post</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Skills"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>Skills</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/SavedSocials"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>Social</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>Gallery</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>Images</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Gallery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Galleries</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Youtube"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span>Youtube</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>Users</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Users</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Activations"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Activations</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>Structure</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Grid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>Grids</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Category"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>Categories</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <header class="navheader"> <span class="logo"><a href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/256x64"></a></span>

  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-full">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left col-md-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/Posts"><b>Posts</b></a>

          </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form pull-right" role="search">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>

              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" role="main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 well">Something</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <form id="login-dp" class="form well" role="form" method="post" action="/login" id="UserLoginForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="data[User][username]" id="UserUsername" placeholder="Username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="data[User][password]" class="form-control" id="UserPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="help-block"><a href="/Register">Register an account!</a>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">remember me</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked well">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Dashboard</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>You</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/MultiPosts/Post"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Post</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Skills"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span>Skills</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/SavedSocials"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>Social</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>Gallery</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Images"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>Images</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Gallery"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Galleries</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Youtube"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span>Youtube</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>Users</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Users</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Activations"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Activations</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><span><b>Structure</b></span>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Grid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>Grids</a>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/Dashboard/Category"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>Categories</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```